# how to convert object[] into datatable

Tags: c#, object, datatable

I have an object array in following format

```
Obj - {object[3]}

obj[0]
obj[1]
obj[2]

obj[1] - count = 6
    [0] - key = "key0"
        value = "value0"
    [1] - key = "key1"
        value = "value1"
    [2] - key = "key2"
        value = "value2"
    [3] - key = "key3"
        value = "value3"
    [4] - key = "key4"
        value = "value4"
    [5] - key = "key5"
        value = "value5"

and so on
```

I am trying to convert this object into datatable so that I will get datatable in following format

```
Key0    Key1    Key2    Key3    Key4    Key5
-----------------------------------------------
Value0  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
```

I tried to convert this object into dictionary and then into datatable.
But not able to do this.

EDIT

I have created dictionery but from here not able to move forward.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    Dictionary<string, string>.KeyCollection pair1 = dictionary.Keys;

                    foreach (string key in pair1)
                    { 

                    }
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: 5000 reputation and still lazy.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Creating the dictionary? Converting it to a DataTable?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: please see my edit. dictionary is created successfully but I am looking for way from which datatable can be generated directly from object array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give us any information about the dictionary or the datatable structure. Still from what I know there is no easy way to import data from dictionary to datatable, so I would try the old way of looping, like this:

```
DataRow temprow;    

foreach (string key in pair1)
{
    temprow= table.NewRow();
    row["key"] = key;
    row["value"] = dictionary["key"];
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```